# How to filter by date on firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm making a page that user can filtar tasks by date, and in my documents I have some tasks that time is with 00:00:00 on timestamp and in my variables i set hours like that, but it isn't returning those documents, that's my code so far:

```
date1 = new Date(), date2 = new Date();
date1.setHours(0, 0, 0), date2.setHours(23, 59, 59);
```

and that's my query:

```
this.db.collection<any>(`tasks`, ref => ref.orderBy('date', 'asc').where('date', '>=', date1).where('date', '<=', date2)).snapshotChanges().pipe(take(1), map(results => {
      return results.map(r => {
        const data = r.payload.doc.data();
        const id = r.payload.doc.id;
        return { data, id };
      });
    }
```

Comment: 1) Can you edit your question to show a screenshot of the Firebase console with a document from the `tasks` collection that you expect to be returned bu this query? 2) I recommend reproducing the problem with only the JavaScript SDK, so without AngularFire, as it'll make it much more likely that people can help.

Comment: I figure it out today, I just add another 0 on my date1 setHours, date1.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0), now returns all documents I need. Thanks for comment.

Comment: Good to hear you got it working Gustavo! .   You might want to write that solution up into a small answer with an explanation, so that future visitors can also benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

I fix my problem by adding another 0, on my date1 setHours, `date1.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)`.